# Customize search results by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have different categories where the post displayed are characterized by different elements, for this reason when I use the search in wordpress the results are not shown very well.
For this reason I would like to change the appearance of the post shown in the search results based on its category.
Example:
[image: What I have now and what I would like to have. Image example.]

My search.php template look like this:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="padder">

        <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_search' ); ?>

        <div class="page" id="blog-search" role="main">

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>


                <?php bp_dtheme_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_post' ); ?>
<div class="blog-post">
// Here is displayed the blog post style and features
</div><!--blog-post-->
<div class="clear"> </div>

                    <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php bp_dtheme_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <h2 class="center"><?php _e( 'No posts found. Try a different search?', 'OneCommunity' ); ?></h2>

            <?php endif; ?>
<div style="display:inline">
<center><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></center>
</div>

        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_search' ); ?>

        </div><!-- .padder -->
    </div><!-- #content -->


<div id="sidebar">
    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-blog')) : ?><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-ad-blog')) : ?><?php endif; ?>
</div><!--sidebar ends-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried to achieve the result of displaying based on the post category a different "template" for the post but without success.
I asked the same question on wordpress.stackexchange.com but without success, and there I pointed out a non working solution, hope it can help you in developing the code I need.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141856/different-layout-on-search-page-depending-on-category-post

Thank you very much for any help you will give, and excuse me for my english.

Comment: You have an answer in the question you linked, simply do a series of if/else based the the category id

Comment: Yes, of course but the answer was not very useful and the solution i provided don't work with my code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could simply use the [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) function:

```
<div <?php post_class( 'blog-post' );?> >
    // Here is displayed the blog post style and features
</div><!--blog-post-->
```

This will render like:

```
<div class="post-3654 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-buildings blog-post">
    // Here is displayed the blog post style and features
</div><!--blog-post-->
```

for posts in the `buildings` category.

Then your CSS will take care of the rest:

```
.post.category-buildings {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

But I think your setup/idea is only suitable for  **single** category posts.

Ref: From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class):

> The `post_class` may include one or more of the following values for the
>   class attribute, dependent upon the pageview.
>
> - .post-id
> - .post
> - .attachment
> - .sticky
> - .hentry (hAtom microformat pages)
> - .category-ID
> - .category-name
> - .tag-name
> - .format-name

Comment: This solution could be applied if i would have to change only the style, but i have to add also php code and other things based on the category of the post. And yes the post usually has only one category.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, that you're also going to add some extra php code as well as styling the posts. You can always define your own functions or actions where the callback takes the current post id or categories as an input or custom `get_template_part` based on the category info.

Comment: Then i should wrap into an if_category_id than get the right template part... I will try this solution and then post the code if it will work.